# {display : none } for the specific div in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, hide, element

[hide div element in iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkvxd.png)1 : I want to hide the div 
2:  div class which is landing-header-right

how to specific div element {display : none}

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide some codes

Comment: <div id="content">
    <div style="height:400px;">
      <div style="border: 2px solid #D5CC5A; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 575px;">
        <iframe [src]="urlSafe" 
          style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -36px; height: 812px; margin-top: -186px; margin-bottom : -186px; width: 650px;">    
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

You could hide `landing-header-right` with internal css or external css like:

```
.landing-header-right {
    display: none;
}
```

You can also hide using inline css like:

```
<div class="landing-header-right" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Obviously, first one is more appreciable. If there are many `landing-header-right` and you wanted to hide that specific one, then you could give id or extra class to hide that element. In html, you could add `hide-iframe` id in the same div and use the css:

```
// html
<div id="hide-iframe" class="landing-header-right" style="display: none;"></div>

// css
#hide-iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

In your case:

```
// Remove extra style
<iframe [src]="urlSafe" style="border: 0px; margin-left: -36px; height: 812px; margin-top: -186px; margin-bottom : -186px; width: 650px; display: none;">
   <div id="hide-iframe" class="landing-header-right"></div> 
</iframe
```

Comment: thank you ! its not working.         <iframe [src]="urlSafe" 
          style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -36px; height: 812px; margin-top: -186px; margin-bottom : -186px; width: 650px;">    
          <div id="hide-iframe" class="landing-header-right" style="display: none;"></div>
        </iframe>

Comment: sorry !its not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vazxp4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html here is my stackblitz code